# Hourly Average of csv data of 15 minutes interval

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

My data in csv files is 15 minutes average and I want to hourly Average. When I used below code, it is showing error. 'how' unrecognised argument.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sirifort_with_data.csv",parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'])
data.resample('H', how='mean')
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, [`pandas.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample) does not have a keyword argument named `how`. You only use that function to group your time-series data. After applying the function, you could apply another to apply operations on each sample/group. Since you want to calculate the average of each group, you can use `.mean()`:

```
data.resample('H').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sirifort_with_data.csv")
df['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_Stamp'])
df = df.set_index('Time_Stamp').resample('H').mean()
```

After converting the Time_Stamp to pd.to_datetime, it worked fine.
Thanks for the help.